# How do I center text horizontally in a Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I would like to know, how to center Text horizontally in Flutter I tried it with an Align Widget before and it did not work. Now, I have tried it with the textAlign property and it still does not work.
Here is the Code for the full Container:

````
```
Container(
            height: 150.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              color: Colors.white10,
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                        'Coursename',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        'Latest post or assignment by the teacher.',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```
````

Below, there is a screenshot, of how the App looks right now.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center, // Align however you like (i.e .centerRight, centerLeft)
  child: Text("This is what I wanted to center"),
),
```

EDIT:

This even centers vertically

```
child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "this is what I center",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I want to center the text horizontally not vertically

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center/Center.html) and add your element as Center's child.

I managed to reach what you need with a mixed solution of Center() and textAlign. They behave differently according to their parents.
However here's a centered text version of your code.

```
Container(
        height: 150.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        child: Center( 
          child:Column(
            children: [
                Center( 
                  child: Text(
                    'Coursename',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ), //Center
              
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column( 
                      children: [
                        Center( 
                          child:Text(
                            'Latest post or assignment by the teacher.',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color:                                         Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ), //Center
                      ], 
                    ),
                ), //Center
               ),
            ],
          ),
        ), //Center
      ),
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not work for me as the text position stayed the same

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can in `Row` use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` 
code snippet

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Coursename',
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 150.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.white10,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Coursename',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Text(
                    'Latest post or assignment by the teacher.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```